# Probluem in connecting to mongo database through PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, connection, database

I have installed mongo db through terminal. but connecting to mongodb through php is not working.

Comment: Please post more info on what you tried i.e code and errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have installed Mongo as a service, you need to start a mongod process first before you will be able to connect to it using mongo. mongod is the actually database server, whereas mongo is the client. Check mongodb.org for instructions on how to run mongod as a service, instructions will differ depending on what platform you are using.

If you are using windows:
Go to Program Files > MongoDB > SERVER > version > bin  run mongod.exe